# Getting data from some rest API on Django

Tags: python, django, python-requests

So here's the deal:
I have some nodeJS/PHP rest API! And I need to build a Django app which feeds on that API. Everything will be done on the server-side! So I would not use Django's back-end structure.
Basically I would GET some JSONs and POST it back so the server, which in turn would process that data. How should I proceed? I've been looking for tutorials for a while now.

However everywhere I look, people are using django-rest or something "django friendly". I tried to start using python-requests but it is still kind of cloudy, am I letting my front-end unprotected using direct GET/POST calls to the server (using requests)!?

Any guidance would be much appreciate!

Comment: Does it have to be Django? Considering that you don't need to build an administration area, a [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/) + [Requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/) solution can give you what you need.

Comment: Oh! Sorry, never saw it had an answer! Yes... It has to be Django :/
It just that. It will get kind of redundant. I mean, do I leave the models in blank...?